# Coloring mesh vertices based on distance from a point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a collision detection simulation and want to make it obvious where a collision has occured. As I have compound colliders, I only want to color the vertices of the collided meshes, which are within a certain distance from the collision. I've been thinking about a sphere with a constraint light source inside, but that was not possible.

Comment: Have you considered a simple pixelshader? Computing color based on distance to a constant point should be very simple.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unclear what exactly is your question.

I assume you already have the collision and the distance part figured out but you'd like to assign colors to the vertices somehow? If that's so you can just use Unity's `Color.Lerp(startColor, endColor, normalizedDistance)` where `normalizedDistance = currentDistanceFromPoint/maximumDistanceFromPoint` to find the point and assign it like so:

```
        Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
        Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
        Color[] colors = new Color[vertices.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
            colors[i] = Color.Lerp(Color.red, Color.green, normalizedDistance);
        mesh.colors = colors;
```